# How to find out what modules are used in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke

There some modules installed in DNN, but not all of them is used. How to find out what modules are used in DNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Host, Extensions pages.  Scroll down, looking for the column that tells you if the module is in use.  If it is, you can drill down to locate the portals and pages where it is used.

That said, you probably should not uninstall the modules that come with DNN.  Only delete unused third-party modules.